# MAMP: Undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I am relatively new to using PHP and MySQL and have run into trouble with the following code.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
                $stmt->close();
                return $user;
            }
```

The error:
**Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()** is produced on the running of this script presumably due to [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/mamp-pro/) not supporting `mysqlnd`. I have tried to work out how to install the native driver to MAMP but it does not look possible - (I have submitted a bug report and would suggest other MAMP users do so as well).

The line below seems to be the issue:

```
 $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Can anyone suggest an alternative method of producing the same outcome but without `mysqlnd`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your phpinfo(). I have mysqlnd, but only the PDO exension. You can tell by looking a the API Extensions under the mysqlnd section (if mysqlnd is installed).

Instead of re-writing everything in PDO, this worked for me:

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT name, email, api_key, status, created_at FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $api_key, $status, $created_at);

        /* fetch values */
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

        /* set values */
        $user['name'] = $name;
        $user['email'] = $email;
        $user['api_key'] = $api_key;
        $user['created_at'] = $created_at;

        $stmt->close();
        return $user;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: This is how I eventually solved the issue, I forgot to add the code to this question. Thanks for your response